# Spring Batch :- Running Job in two stages

Tags: spring-batch

Here is the spring batch design for job recommending to my client:-

UI application will call Rest API on API server. Rest API creates a unique id , and send unique id, job params, job name as jms message to some batch server.  Rest API sends the unique token id to UI.

JMS message listener on batch server create a new spring batch job instance and set up unique id as job param and run the job.

UI keeps on polling the Status Rest API by passing the unique token.

Rest API finds from job param table for unique id, job execution id and provide the job status to UI.

Please advise, any suggestion so that we can create the job on API server, so that job instance and param created but does not execute any steps. We know the job execution id

On batch server with input job execution id, we can rerun/resume the job again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a JobRequest-table to store the initial request with the initial unique token. You could pass this token to the JMS server along with the batch request. As soon as the JMS batch server creates/starts the request it should also update the JobRequest-table and insert the actual Batch-JobInstance-Id.

So clients can ask the status by using the unique token. Rest-API server can use that token to look up the job id and get information about the job progress

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by providing my own incrementer factory while creating the  Job Repository bean. Now I can get the job execution from  Seq at UI layer and use same while running  job. Job execution id is stored in thread local at batch server. I am overrirding the getNextKey() method from OracleSequenceMaxValueIncrementer

Answer (score -1):

I was debugging the Spring batch code. I came with this approach. But now trying to worked it out, see this works :-

My client using oracle DB. Spring Batch provides this property in batch-oracle.properties file.
batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.OracleSequenceMaxValueIncrementer
I will override the batch.database.incrementer.class property by 
client specific incrementer class by subclassing OracleSequenceMaxValueIncrementer and override getNextKey() abstract method.

On API server, I will call only job execution sequence, get the id and pass same in jms message.

On batch server, store the job execution id in some thread local. getNextKey() method check if  incrementer name is JOB EXEC SEQ, get the id from thread local else create the way spring batch is doing it. getNextKey() will be called during job execution creation by spring batch. For other tables sequence, this will not cause issue as incrementer name will be diff.